# Editing row after finding all its values with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to edit a cell after finding row through user input.

```
df = pd.read_excel(file)

memory = input("Select Memory : ")

# Match and keep columns
a = df.columns
b = ['IDC S/N', 'ECC', 'Cabinet Qty', 'MMEX', 'VDR']
keep_columns = [x for x in a if x in b]

# Look within IDC S/N for user input 
df = df.loc[df.loc[:, 'IDC S/N'].fillna('nan').str.lower().str.contains(memory.lower()), :, ][
                    keep_columns]
                df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Output :

```
   ECC    IDC S/N  Cabinet Qty  MMEX  VDR
0  Yes  H532G070S           19     8    0
```

I would like to edit the Cabinet Qty.

What was tried so far :

```
df.loc[df.loc[:, "IDC S/N"].fillna('nan').str.lower().str.contains(memory.lower()), :, ]['Cabinet Qty']
```

Output:

```
# 19 Equals Cabinet Qty 
8    19
Name: Cabinet Qty, dtype: int64
```

Yet this one throws an error :

```
S/N"].fillna('nan').str.lower().str.contains(memory.lower()), :, ]['Cabinet Qty'] == ['50']
```

Output:

```
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (0,), (1,))
```

Help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is possible simplify - removed `fillna`, because possible add `na` parameter to [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and removed double `[]` for use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df["IDC S/N"].str.lower().str.contains(memory.lower(), na=False), 'Cabinet Qty'] = 50
```

Comment: Sweet. thanks for anwsering something so basic :) 
care to explain what the na=False is for?

Comment: @EllieHodjayev - If `NaN`s in column it processing like `False`, so can remove `fillna` ;)